# Hops to put in a golden ale to give a big hit of hops

Tags: hops, secondary-fermentation, brewing, extract-brewing

Im looking to make a golden ale from a kit but I want it to have a massive hoppy hit when you take a sip, any ideas on what type to add and dates before bottling?

Comment: Are you interested in adding hop bitterness, or hop aroma? For the first, you need to  add hops to the boil. For the second, they can be added at the start of fermentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add saaz at the end of boiling (0 min) and dry hopping with more saaz 2 days before bottling.  You could check hops characterists at hopunion: https://www.hopunion.com/saaz/

Comment: Im a kit brewer, should I add some finishing hops when I start fermentation and add more before bottling?

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] (I only now saw the secondary comment)
If you want to Dry Hop (add hops after primary fermentation has completed) then I usually add about 50g of the same hops that was the "lead character" in the brew. Dry hopping is usually 3 to 7 days before bottling/kegging.

Just add the hops to the fermenter. Don't do anything like boiling the hops. Just weight it out, open the fermenter, throw them in and close the fermenter.

Using pellets is the best as they "dissolve" and distribute nicely. For the rest you might need to use a bag that is weighed down.

[End of Edit]

A "Massive Hoppy Hit" is a bit difficult. Do you want bitter, flavour or aroma? What do you consider a hoppy hit?
Basically: 
To make it more bitter, add extra hops at beginning of boil.
To make it taste more hoppy, add hops halfway during boil.
To make it smell more hoppy, add hops at end of boil or dry hop.

What flavour/aroma do you want to achieve? Citrus? Then go for Cascade or a similar hop. Berries? Then EKG or similar. Spicy? Then Saaz.

High alpha hops will give more bitterness.